# Удаление цвета из текстуры в фрагментном шейдере

Tags: opengl, opengles, glsl

У меня есть текстура залитая хромакеем (к примеру vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)), на ее определенную область накладывается текстура красного цвета с альфа каналом (к примеру vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5)), в фрагментном шейдере я делаю проверку:

```
if (texture.a == 1.0 && texture.r == 0.0 && texture.g == 1.0 && texture.b == 0.0) {
  discard;
}
```

При отрисовке на экран весь зеленый удаляется, но зеленый остается в месте наложения красной текстуры ("под" красной текстурой так как при наложении цвета смешались). Как удалить хромакей на месте наложения двух текстур ("под" красной текстурой) ?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98123/discussion-on-question-by-alexander-gima------).

Answer (score 2):

Всех ваших требований не знаю, но как я понял, вам просто надо удалить весь зеленый. Для этого после

```
if (texture.a == 1.0 && texture.r == 0.0 && texture.g == 1.0 && texture.b == 0.0) {
  discard;
}
```

можно так же проверять

```
if (texture.g != 0.0) {
  //тут у финального цвета фрагмента убираем green
  finalFragColor.g = 0.0;
}
```

Работать будет так: все чисто зеленые фрагменты удалить, c оставшихся фрагментов убрать зеленый оттенок без их удаления.